# Translate JOIN with AND clause into Lambda

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this query in RAW sql:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.SourceUser_Id
FROM UserInteractions b
JOIN UserInteractions x on x.SourceUser_Id=1 and x.TargetUser_Id=b.SourceUser_Id
```

UserInteractions is a table that connects the User table in a many-many relationship with itself (to create friendship relationships).

This query returns all the UserInteractions that are mutual (I.E: it returns only the UserInteractions who's targets have friended you back.

The sql query is working perfectly, however I can't figure out how to translate this into EntityFramework's lambda.

I need a way for this thing to work with the Join() method.

Comment: The LINQ is exactly the same as it would normally be. You just use the C# `&&` instead of `AND`

Comment: Oh, oops, I actually meant lambda, not linq .. I updated the question to reflect this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
var s = from b in UserInteractions 
             join x in UserInteractions on b.TargetUser_Id equals x.TargetUser_Id
             where x.SourceUser_Id == 1
                         select b.SourceUser_Id;
```

Lambda:

```
var s = query.Join(db.UserInteractions,
            f => f.TargetUser,
            p => p.SourceUser,
            (f, p) => new {f, p }).Where(x=>x.f.SourceUser == 1).Select(p=>p.f);
```

Comment: Hi, even though I changed my question to request for a lambda response, your linq response was constructive enough for me to figure out the lambda! thanks! Hope you don't mind me editing your question to show the lambda response

Comment: @Furyvore - np...its a great edit ... ppl can see different implementation side by side.